# Installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 can't get into Ubuntu now

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, uefi

I have installed Ubuntu using a DVD alongside Windows10, but now if I startup the PC, it will automatically boot into win.

On the internet I found out, that if win is installed in UEFI mode, and ubuntu in BIOS it will not boot into the OS-chooser, but I only have a BIOS, so I don't think that my Windows is installed in UEFI. Also, when first tried installing Ubuntu, I chose the UEFI way and it told me, that windows was not installed in UEFI and that there will be a problem, so I chose the normal (SATA) way and then it didn't show any option.

Also what may be problematic is that I installed Linux on a seperate HDD than windows is installed...

So how do I get my Windows to display the OS-choose-screen before it boots into Windows?

Thanks
Hiro

Comment: Any factory installed Windows 10 is in UEFI mode and, by your own admission, you refused to install Ubuntu in the same way when prompted by the arguably misleading message. Installing in a different drive has no influence whatsoever. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 1):

> I only have a BIOS, so I don't think that my Windows is installed in UEFI. Also, when first tried installing Ubuntu, I chose the UEFI way

This statement is internally inconsistent. If you could choose a UEFI boot option, then you have an EFI, not a BIOS. (Note that UEFI is Unified EFI, aka EFI 2.x. I use "EFI" to refer to any variety of EFI, including UEFI, as "EFI" is the more general term.) You're probably confused because of the bad habit of many manufacturers to refer to their EFIs as BIOSes. I suspect they do this because many people have at least a vague idea of what a BIOS is, and as an EFI fills a similar role, it's easier for the manufacturer to use the term "BIOS" where they really should be using "EFI" or "UEFI"; but this practice creates confusion because people like you see "BIOS" in the documentation or computer's screens and think they've got a BIOS. People also see "BIOS" and drag in BIOS-specific knowledge that's just plain wrong on EFI-based computers. In fact, though, BIOS and EFI are two entirely different types of firmware, much like a pickup truck and airplane are two entirely different types of vehicle.

You may want to read more background information on what EFIs are, how they work, and how they differ from BIOSes:

- **[Adam Williamson's blog entry on how EFI works](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/)** -- This page describes the theory behind EFI-mode booting.
- **[A question and answers on the differences between BIOS and EFI booting on Superuser.com](http://superuser.com/questions/496026/what-is-the-difference-in-boot-with-bios-and-boot-with-uefi)** -- This provides the basics of the preceding, but is more concise.
- **[My page on installing Linux on EFI systems](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/)** -- This page is a more practical introduction to EFI-mode booting than Adam Williamson's blog.
- **[My page on the CSM](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html)** -- This page covers the Compatibility Support Module (CSM), including when it's useful and when it's not.
- **[The Ubuntu community wiki entry on UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)** -- This page is a bit disjointed, but is the most Ubuntu-specific introduction to EFI and its issues.

> I chose the UEFI way and it told me, that windows was not installed in UEFI and that there will be a problem, so I chose the normal (SATA) way and then it didn't show any option.

This reveals more confusion over terminology. [Serial ATA (SATA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA) is a hardware standard for connecting hard disks to computer motherboards or disk controller cards. It makes no sense in the context in which you've used it. I suspect you mean BIOS/CSM/legacy.

It's certainly possible to install Windows in BIOS mode, but all computers that shipped from major manufacturers (Dell, HP, Acer, Sony, etc.) with Windows 10 installed shipped with it installed to boot in EFI mode. Thus, chances are you either installed Windows yourself in BIOS mode or you're misinterpreting or mis-remembering the error message you saw. It's hard to know which of these is the case (or if it's something more exotic) without more information, and understanding your current configuration is critical for fixing it.

I realize that this is a long response and it doesn't come close to answering your question. Unfortunately, you haven't provided the details necessary for me to do more than guess about your real issue. If you want more help, please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) from an Ubuntu installer in its "try before installing" mode and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

---

**EDIT:**  Based on your [Boot Repair summary,](https://paste2.org/xVXa1D5f) it looks like your computer is EFI-based, but both Windows and Ubuntu are installed in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. GRUB (the Ubuntu boot loader) is installed to the MBR of `/dev/sda`, and the Windows boot loader is installed to the MBR of `/dev/sdb`. Ubuntu and Windows seem to be installed mostly to `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`, respectively, although there's one NTFS partition on `/dev/sda`.

Thus, it looks like your system is set up correctly, at least in terms of on-disk data structures. Chances are your booting straight to Windows is caused by the boot order in your firmware. I recommend launching the firmware setup utility and adjusting the boot order so that what Linux calls `/dev/sda` (a Hitachi HDP72505 disk) is first in the boot order. Unfortunately, the details of how to do this vary greatly from one computer to another. You usually access the setup utility by hitting Esc, Enter, or a function key shortly after powering on the computer, before the GRUB menu or any OS-specific messages appear. If you need more help with this, or can't find a boot order option, you should ask the manufacturer or ask on a manufacturer-centric forum.

As you asked about it, it *is* possible to convert both Windows and Ubuntu to boot in EFI mode; however, the process is tedious and runs a risk of making matters worse. Thus, I don't recommend doing this unless you become desperate -- and even then, only if you back up your important data first. You could try [this new Microsoft tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt) or [this older procedure](https://web.archive.org/web/20170306032145/http://sdnalloh.com/converting-win7-from-mbr-to-gpt/) to convert Windows from BIOS-mode to EFI-mode booting. For Ubuntu, you could install my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) *after* converting Windows or run Boot Repair *from an EFI-mode boot* (which is how you booted it to get the summary data). In either case, you'll need an [EFI System Partition (ESP),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) which the Windows conversion process should create.

Comment: Ok I have done the BootInfo Summary. Here it is: http://paste2.org/xVXa1D5f Hope it helps, to SATA: In my BIOS (or EFI or whatever) it said either to boot the DVD via SATA or UEFI mode, UEFI got the error in installation and SATA worked, but didnt get the Windows OS chooser...

Comment: Could I just reinstall Ubuntu choosing the UEFI mode and then everything would work as intended? Or maybe is there any way I can "copy" my installation to UEFI?

Comment: You have UEFI hardware. You UEFI booted Ubuntu live installer to run Boot-Repair, but both installs on both hard drives are BIOS/MBR. Reboot in BIOS mode, may be called CSM - UEFI Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which emulates a BIOS mode. Do not run any auto fix in Boot-Repair. That installs grub to both MBR, if seen as internal drives. Grub only boots working Windows. So Windows cannot need chkdsk and cannot be hibernated. But script says is it hibernated. Directly boot Windows drive and turn off fast start up. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions

Comment: I don't really get what you mean. I turned off fast start up and what do I do now?

Comment: Please see my edit to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked for me to change the Boot Order to first the Linux HDD, so that grub would load and now I can choose between Win10 and Ubuntu, TY